# Creating a custom RWD theme for magento

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme

I'm writing my own RWD theme for magento, `magento is really stubborn` and I do have lot of patience :D
Got an error now.
Here is my custom header.phtml

```
<div id="topbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topbar_cmslinks') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="user-links col-md-4">
                <span class="welcome pull-left">
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('header')->getWelcome() ?>
                </span>
                <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a title="<?php echo $this->__('My Account') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account') ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->__('My Account') ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a title="Log Out" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout') ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->__('Logout') ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/login/')?>">
                            <?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></a></li>
                        </li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/create/')?>">
                            <?php echo $this->__('Create Account') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the error that I got after saving that phtml file and refreshing magento was:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:73:"Invalid method Mage_Cms_Block_Block::(Array
(
    [0] => top_cmslinks
)
)";i:1;s:2124:"#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Cms_Block_Block->('top_cmslinks')
#2 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 C:\wamp\www\finalcustommagento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:30:"/finalcustommagento/index.php/";s:11:"script_name";s:29:"/finalcustommagento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Struck here, please help me.
Here is custom layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"/>
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
        <!-- <reference name=""
        <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/> -->
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="cms/block" name="top_cmslinks" as="top_cmslinks">
                <action type="setBlockId">
                    <block_id>top_cmslinks</block_id>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference> 
    </default>   
</layout>
```

Comment: By the error message it seams to me you have something else in one of the layout files. Something like `<action...>` but without a `method` attribute. Please post your custom layout file.

Comment: @Marius: I've edited the question and added custom layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, this is your problem:

```
<action type="setBlockId">
    <block_id>top_cmslinks</block_id>
</action>
```

Should be

```
<action method="setBlockId">
    <block_id>top_cmslinks</block_id>
</action>
```

replace `type` with `method`.

Comment: Can you tell me about disabling wysiwyg compiler in magento? It is messing my custom links in header part.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni I don't understand what you mean. I think it's best to ask an other question and explain what the problem is. Maybe add some screenshots as visual aid.

Comment: Okay, Marius....